# How to prevent user typing backspace at beginning of a line if previous line is max characters

Tags: html, jquery

I have textarea that every line is limited to 70 characters.
Here is my code:

```
var MAX_LENGTH_PER_LINE=70;

$('#txtComment').keypress(function (e) {

if(e.key != 'Enter'){

       var CursorPosition=document.getElementById('txtComment').selectionStart;

       var lines = $(this).val().split("\n");
      
       var sum=0;

       for (var i=0; i < lines.length; i++)

       {

              if(lines[i].length >= MAX_LENGTH_PER_LINE && CursorPosition > sum && CursorPosition <= lines[i].length + sum + i){

                     e.preventDefault();

                     alert("Max characters for comment - 70");

                     break;

              }

              sum+=lines[i].length;
          
       }

}

});
```

It works very nice, exept of one case, when user press backspace at beggining of a line, the line he pressed on, passed to end of previous line also if its full in 70 characters.

My problem is i am using keypress, and its not recognize backspace, i searched and saw i need to use keydown or keyup but i cant use it because they fired before text includes the new string user typed and i need to check text after change and if its more than 70 characters, to prevent typing, another problem is that keypress is not recognize e.preventDefault because it fired after typing occurred.

So how to check text with new string user type, and prevent it if its more than 70 characters?

please, any idea, i am working on it three days....

Comment: I think you can use the following code in order to recognize a backspace. if(e.keyCode == '8' || e.keyCode == '8'){
        alert('You pressed a "backspace" key in textbox');  
    }

Comment: But its not even get into the function when its backspace...